# Detecting ArcGIS Server on computer?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3

How do I know if my ArcGIS 9.3.1 has a GIS server on my computer?

Comment: Do you want to know if the software is installed, or if you have services up and running?

Comment: Please supply more specifics.  Is this a Windows computer or UNIX?  Are you looking for a particular flavor of GIS Server, or just any sort of software capable of serving GIS content?

Comment: I am not familiar with the server side. Is it an extension ? or does it come with the Desktop package ? I check and went  into the ArcGIS Desktop Admin but it does not mention it.

Comment: By the way, Is there a tutorial book that can I read about ArcGIS Server for 9.3.1 ? I don't know if my agency will have the 10 anytime soon. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for their quick respond to my question. It looks like we do not have a separate ArcGIS Server. I will try and convince my agency to include it when it comes to ArcGIS 10. I will continue and keep learning how to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: When you do get 10.0 and see ArcSOMP.exe and ArcSOCP.exe processes, this doesn't mean ArcGIS server is installed.  At 10.0 these are the desktop geoprocessor, running in separate processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GIS Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/10.0/about) is a pretty detailed install.
[This tells a lot about what AGServer](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/10.0/about) can do.

Here are some resources for AGS 9.3.1.
[Tutorial](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3.1/dotNet/)
[Components of AGS system](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3.1/dotNet/components_of_server.htm#)
[What comes with AGS](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3.1/dotNet/whats_included.htm#)

Answer (score 7):

A quick way to tell if an ArcGIS Server is up and running on your computer is to check via the [Rest API](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/):

```
 http://<your_computer_name_here>/arcgis/rest/services
```

If you get to a page with some basic map service related options, the service is running. If you get an error, ArcGIS Server may be installed, but it's probably not running.

**EDIT: Response to comment**

Here are the default URLS for the REST API for both editions of ArcGIS Server:

```
Java: http://<host>:8399/argis/rest
.NET: http://<host>/arcgis/rest
```

These are the default URLs unless changes are made to the [configuration](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/rest/index.html?config.html) of the REST API. If you've gotten that far, you probably know whether or not ArcGIS Server is installed on your computer.

Comment: I disagree.  If Java edition, there will be a port number.  COuld also be a port number on .NET edition.